Did Yakuza attack US soldiers post-WWII?
According to this link Did any Yakuza fight for Japan during WWII? on Quora, a poster said "The Yakuza in post WW2 Japan formed groups that killed US occupying soldiers that they found abusing or raping citizens. Because the Yakuza unlike the regular Japanese civilians had access to a lot of weapons". Is this historically accurate or just an anti-American fabrication?

A place to start digging : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_during_the_occupation_of_Japan#Reported_rapes_by_US_forces

This question is similar to: Did any civil resistence against the allied occupation of Japan exist?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DanM  I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The suggested duplicate is about resistance to the occupation whereas this is about retaliation against specific abuses by the occupation forces.

@DanM Hi, no. My question is specifically about whether the Yakuza actually had murdered some US soldiers during post-World War 2 that they found abusing or raping citizens. Is that actually happened or just unverified statements made by anti-Americans?

@SnoopyKid, please don't comment. Edit the question to address the concerns raised in comments, then flag the comments for deletion.

another place to start digging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_activities_in_Japan#Contacts_with_the_Yakuza
